# Java Booleans not updating

Tags: java, boolean

First of all, sorry if I mess up, it's my first question here. Second, sorry for my messy code, I just started learning java at school.

So, I coded a timer that goes up from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59. The seconds, minutes, and hours go up using inner and outer for loops and are then printed every second in the console. I got a boolean that checks if the values are less than 10. If the number is less than 10, it adds a 0 before the number so that it's printed as 01:02:03 instead of 1:2:3. The problem is that the program doesn't update the value of the booleans once the values are equal or greater than 10, printing 010:011:012 instead of 10:11:12. Any ideas?

```java
public class Clock {
    
    int seconds = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    boolean hoursLess10;
    boolean minutesLess10;
    boolean secondsLess10;
    String secondDisplay;
    String minuteDisplay;
    String hourDisplay;
    String timeDisplay;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clock m = new Clock();
        m.startClock();
    }
    
    public void startClock() {
        try {
            for (int hourElapse = 0; hourElapse < 24; hourElapse++) {
                if (hours < 10) {
                    hoursLess10 = true;
                } else {
                    hoursLess10 = false;
                }
                
                for (int minuteElapse = 0; minuteElapse < 60; minuteElapse++) {
                    if (minutes < 10) {
                        minutesLess10 = true;
                    } else {
                        minutesLess10 = false;
                    }
                    
                    for (int secondElapse = 0; secondElapse < 60; secondElapse++) {
                        if (seconds < 10) {
                            secondsLess10 = true;
                        } else if (seconds >= 10) {
                            secondsLess10 = false;
                        }
                        displayTime();
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        seconds++;
                    }
                    
                    seconds = 0;
                    minutes++;
                }

                minutes = 0;
                hours ++;
            }
            hours = 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        
        System.out.println(hoursLess10);
        System.out.println(minutesLess10);
        System.out.println(secondsLess10);
    }
    
    public boolean displaySeconds() {
        if (secondsLess10 = true) {
            /*secondDisplay = (String) "0" + seconds;*/
            System.out.println("0" + seconds);
        } else {
            /*secondDisplay = (String) "" + seconds;*/
            System.out.print(seconds);
        }
        
        return secondsLess10;
    }
    
    public boolean displayMinutes() {
        if (minutesLess10 = true) {
            /*minuteDisplay = (String) "0" + minutes;*/
            System.out.print("0" + minutes);
            System.out.print(":");
        } else {
            /*minuteDisplay = (String) "" + minutes;*/
            System.out.print(minutes);
            System.out.print(":");
        }
        
        return minutesLess10;
    }

    public boolean displayHours() {
        if (hoursLess10 = true) {
            /*hourDisplay = (String) "0" + hours;*/
            System.out.print("0" + hours);
            System.out.print(":");
        } else {
            /*hourDisplay = (String) "" + hours;*/
            System.out.print(hours);
            System.out.print(":");
        }
        
        return hoursLess10;
    }
    
    public void displayTime() {
        displayHours();
        displayMinutes();
        displaySeconds();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (secondsLess10 = true) {` is assigning the value of `true` to the variable `secondsLess`, not checking its value.  To avoid this sort of typo is why it's recommended to always just write `if (secondsLess10) {` instead.

Comment: note that `if (hours < 10) { hoursLess10 = true; } else { hoursLess10 = false; }` can be simplified as `hoursLess10 = ( hours < 10 );` (parenthesis not needed) (same true for minutes and seconds) || and all of them are not necessary if using `System.out.printf()`

Comment: Ok thanks! What @azurefrog said worked perfectly, although I don't really understand what the difference is. I haven't learned what printf does yet, but I'll try it out. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `displayHours`, `displayMinutes` and `displaySeconds` methods, there are mistakes in `if` condition.

When you want to check the boolean variable, you can do it in 2 ways.

```
// == ... check if there are the same

// 1) != ... check if there are not the same

if (minutesLess == 10){
    //To Do Things
    }
    
// 2) if the boolean variable is true, for false it should be !minutesLess

if (minutesLess){
    //To Do Things
    }
```